# Every set of well-ordered sets is well-ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

> Let $W \neq \emptyset$ be a set of well-ordered sets. 
>   Show that there is $A \in W$ that for all $B \in W$, $A$ is order-isomorphic to $B$ or to an initial segment of $B$.

This is from Goldrei, exercise 7.66. Being order-isomorphic to an initial segment is a strict linear order on well-ordered sets, hence the title.

If $\emptyset \in W$ then we can take $A=\emptyset$. In general we should take the set in $W$ with the least order type, but Goldrei asks it before he develops order types, knowing only that this order is linear. So is there any more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any $B\in W$. Consider all initial segments in $B$ that are order isomorphic to *some* $A\in W$. There is a smallest such, since $B$ is well ordered. Take the corresponding $A$.

Comment: The result is of course false if $W=\emptyset$, so we have to assume this is not so.

Comment: Yeah, Goldrei didn't write $W \neq \emptyset$ but should have. I edited.

Comment: Got it. In case B has no initial segment that is isomorphic to an element of W, we should take A=B.  In the other case we prove that A works by letting $D \in W$ and comparing D and B.

Comment: is vacuous truth playing any role when $W = \emptyset$?

Comment: @DacianBonta Not sure if I understand the question. When $W=\emptyset$, there is certainly *no* $A\in W$, let alone one additionally satisfying the other requirements in the problem as stated.

Comment: The statement "for all $B\in W$ such and such A exists" is *vacuously* true for  $W = \emptyset $. Thus $W \neq \emptyset$ is not required, so the statement is true for ALL ordinals. (I think; maybe).

Comment: @DacianBonta Ah, now I see what you mean. But that is not the right way to read the statement: It should be read as follows: “By assumption, there exists some $B\in W$. Pick any of them. Then …” (If you want to be pedantic, though, there is a small gap in my proof: You might imagine there is *no* initial segment of $B$ which is order isomorphic to some $A\in W$. But $B$ itself is such an initial segment, order isomorphic to itself.)